# VB.NET Sort File on new line?

Tags: vb.net, sorting

Im looking at creating an application in VB.NET and im having some issues sorting a file on new line.

Basically on the new line, i wanna capture the data in that line, and store it in an array for later use.

Can anyone help me with this? It'd be greatly appreciated :)

Example in PHP:

```
$data = explode("\n", $a);
```

Comment: `System.IO.File.ReadAllLines()` should do it

Comment: And then i would loop through that data in a for loop and add it to my array i suppose?

Comment: As an aside, if you are new to .Net, consider starting with C#

Comment: What are the advantages to C#?

Comment: This wikipedia article covers things http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_C_Sharp_and_Visual_Basic_.NET. IMHO it all comes down to terseness and support. In c# you have to write less charachters for the same functionality. You'll also get faster c# answers here on StackOverflow (this is just my impression, I have no evidence.)

Comment: @Jodrell I see your reasoning here but thats all preference. I find vb.net faster to the verbose style and not having to worry about curly brackets and semicolons.

Comment: @Intrus, agreed, its just preference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand your question correctly, use this to read a file and load line by line into an array.

```
 Dim myArray() = New String() {} 'Corrected array, instantiated. or use myArray(-1)
 Dim x as Integer = 0

Using reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader("file.txt")
    holdData(x) = reader.ReadLine 'Reads line by Line and stores in array.
         x += 1 'Increase array index by 1 before moving to next line
End Using
```

**EDIT:** Another method, one that i was not aware of and i find it very interesting is:

```
Dim path As String = "data.txt"
Dim holdData() As String = IO.File.ReadAllLines(path)
```

This is two lines of code and does the same as my original response.
Very efficient, all you would need to do from here is use the `holdData()` Array to read the lines of text to a `textbox`, `label`, `listbox` or w/e you wish to do with it :)

Comment: This one works even better, thanks for the updated one! Both ones work as described, this one just a little better. Thanks =)

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/KiZu3.png

Theirs a small hitch, after running i get that error? Any help?

Complete beginner to VB...

Comment: To be honest here, I actually like Jodrell's answer better :) So i gave him +1. I've edited my answer to show what he means in code.

Comment: @RobbyDuke, if the file was large and you didn't want to hold it all in memory at once, `StreamReader` is the way to go.

Comment: @RobbyDuke: the reason you got that error is because although `holdData` is declared it is never created so it is still null when you are trying to write to it.

Comment: @Jodrell Hmm, interesting i did not know that. So in this case if we know the file won't be large then your answer would be efficient, because 1 line of code to read a file into an array is pretty sweet.

Comment: @Chris Thank you Chris! i forgot to instatiate the array, i corrected my code. Thanks again +1 for that!

Comment: @Intrus: In fact if you dig into it both answers turn out to be basically the same. ReadAllLines internally just creates a `List<string>` and then creates a `StreamReader` and loops until it is out of lines adding them to the list before returning it as an array. whcih makes me notice, you don't seem to have your `while ((str = reader.ReadLine()) != null)` type line in there...

Answer (score 3):

Ok, [`System.IO.File.ReadAllLines()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1.aspx#Y0) returns a `string` `Array` so you could just save the return value.

Alternatively you could iterate the result with a `for` or `foreach` loop or use `linq` to so some processing on it. The options are legion and depend on what you want to do.